# Class template specialization using concepts

Tags: c++, template-specialization, c++-concepts, compiler-bug, c++-templates

I'm attempting to use concepts to chose between different specializations of class templates. Unfortunately, 3 different compilers give 3 different results:

- gcc: compiles ok
- clang: Accepts the definitions of 'F()'. Rejects the
  definitions of 'State()'
- MSVC: Rejects both

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <class T> concept is_ENUM = std::is_enum<T>::value;
template <class T> concept is_not_ENUM = !std::is_enum<T>::value;

template <class Token> class FSM
{
};

template <is_ENUM Token> class FSM<Token>
{
public:

  class State
  {
  public:
    State ();
  };

  FSM () = default;

  void F ();
};
 
template <is_ENUM Token> void FSM<Token>::F ()
{
}

template <is_ENUM Token> FSM<Token>::State::State ()
{
}

template <is_not_ENUM Token> class FSM<Token>
{
public:

  class State
  {
  public:
    State ();
  };

  void F ();
};

template <is_not_ENUM Token> void FSM<Token>::F ()
{
}

template <is_not_ENUM Token> FSM<Token>::State::State ()
{   
}

int main ()
{
    enum class T1 {A, B, C};

    FSM <T1> fsm1;
    FSM <int> fsm2;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ed9M4snG3)

I was hoping this was going to work ok. If I inline the definitions, all compilers accept the code.

As far as I can tell, the spec allows this. Have I misunderstood or are these errors just compiler bugs?

Comment: You can instead use `if constexpr` in functions and check for `is_enum` there.

Comment: I bet for compilers' bugs.

Comment: @kiner_shah Thanks, yes that is a possibility. The problem is there are a lot of differences so I thought it cleaner to separate the classes.

Comment: @Rob190 You can also create separate constexpr functions.